How so save a session with nodriver (Python)?
I would like to learn how to save and load a session (cookies) with nodriver. I found an example (https://stabler.tech/blog/nodriver-a-new-webscraping-tool), but the code seems to be outdated.
I found some old github incidents, where the developer said something about it and posted some code. (https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1817  //  https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1816)
I tried different stuff for hours, even with using Gemini and ChatGPT, but I cant do it. Iam pretty new to Python. Could someone help me?
Here is executable example code:
import asyncio
import nodriver as uc

user = "User"
password = "passwort"


async def type_text(element, text):
    for char in text:
        await element.send_keys(char)


async def main():
    browser = None
    try:
        browser = await uc.start()
        page = await browser.get('https://html-php.de/php/zb_php_f/index.php')

        email_field = await page.select("input[name=a_nick]")
        password_field = await page.select("input[name=a_pass]")
        login_task = None

        if email_field and password_field:
            await type_text(email_field, user)
            await type_text(password_field, password)

            login_button = await page.select("input[type=submit]")
            if login_button:
                login_task = asyncio.create_task(login_button.click())

        if login_task:
            await login_task

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during login: {e}")
    finally:
        if browser:
            # Wait for 10 seconds before closing
            await asyncio.sleep(10)
            await browser.stop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uc.loop().run_until_complete(main())

I want to achieve, that the second time I start it, its already logged in. (so the exception should get thrown).
(I couldnt use a "nodriver" tag, so I used "undetected-chromedriver", its the predecessor)

By chance I found a documentation (https://ultrafunkamsterdam.github.io/nodriver/). It was not linked on github, in the ReadMe and at the other info points.
But with that I was able to help myself quite quickly :)
Here is the code, if someone else is interested ^^
import nodriver as uc
import json

USER = "User"
PASSWORD = "passwort"
COOKIE_FILE_NAME = ".session.dat"


async def type_text(element, text):
    for char in text:
        await element.send_keys(char)


async def login_with_credentials(page):
    email_field = await page.select("input[name=a_nick]")
    password_field = await page.select("input[name=a_pass]")

    if not email_field or not password_field:
        return False

    print("Logging in with credentials...")
    await type_text(email_field, USER)
    await type_text(password_field, PASSWORD)

    login_button = await page.select("input[type=submit]")
    if login_button:
        await login_button.click()
        return True

    return False


async def load_cookies(browser, page):
    try:
        await browser.cookies.load(COOKIE_FILE_NAME)
        await page.reload()
        print("Cookies loaded.")
        return True
    except (json.JSONDecodeError, ValueError) as e:
        print(f"Failed to load cookies: {e}")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Cookie file does not exist.")

    return False


async def save_cookies(browser):
    try:
        await browser.cookies.save(COOKIE_FILE_NAME)
        print("Cookies saved.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to save cookies: {e}")


async def main():
    try:
        browser = await uc.start()
        page = await browser.get('https://html-php.de/php/zb_php_f/index.php')

        if not await load_cookies(browser, page):
            if not await login_with_credentials(page):
                print("Login failed.")
                return False

            await save_cookies(browser)
            print("Logged in with credentials and cookies saved.")
        else:
            print("Logged in with cookies.")

        await page.sleep(5)
        # browser.stop()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error during login: {e}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uc.loop().run_until_complete(main())


How did you install the "nodriver" library? I tried install it from pip as the docs in https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/nodriver said, but I get this error message: "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement nodriver (from versions: none)"

pip install nodriver did it for me...
